# Complex line integral in terms of x and y

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Compute the complex line integral $\int (x^2 + iy^2)dz $ over the line segment from 0 to 2+i.

I am struggling to understand what to do with the $x^2 +iy^2 $ term. I have been able to do these more basic complex line integrals such as $\int z dz $ , but for some reason the start to this one just stumps me by not having things in terms of z. I think what I am supposed to do is get $x^2+iy^2$ back in terms of z, but I just don't see how.

I don't want the answer, I just need help understanding what's going on here.

Comment: You technically don't have to get it back in terms of $z$ if you don't want to. You're free to plug in the parametrization once you have it. In this case, a good choice of parameterization would be $z = (2+i)t$. What would the bounds be, and what would $x$ and $y$ be in this case?

Comment: would x just be rcos(theta) and y be rsin(theta) where r would be root 3, or is that way off.

Comment: ? no, $x=2t$ and $y=it$

Comment: oh wait, no I see that yeah. For the bounds would we go from 0 to 1.